# Only one alarm fired when multiple ones are set

Tags: android, flags, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

My goal is to fire an alarm for every event from `eventsDb.getFavouriteEvents()` but only one is fired everytime.

In my opinion, it may be caused by setting `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, however I need this flag to post Extras with an intent. Is there any way not to set this flag and still post Extras with the intent?

I'm storing `PendinIntents` in a Collection (`pendingIntents`) because I'm canceling them in `onDestroy()` of this `Service` class.

This is code from `onCreate()`:

```
for(Event event : eventsDB.getFavouriteEvents()) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmReciever.ONCOMING_EVENT);
  intent.putExtra(Event.TITLE, event.getTitle());

  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(EventAlarmService.this, 0, intent, 
    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, event.getTime(), pendingIntent);

  pendingIntents.add(pendingIntent);
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PendingIntent will be overwritten on send if they share the same code.  Changing the code for each intent on send should correct this problem.

Comment: So this is what the `requestCodes` are for! Thanks : )

Comment: or you can use different actions on the intents to differentiate them. PendingIntent with same intent overwrites previous.